# reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8

I tried to look for similar answer but I didn't get/find a solution yet, then I ask directly exposing my case

I have a static function `validate`

```
    private static void validate(AiNode pNode) {
        ...
            for (AiNode child : pNode.mChildren) {
                doValidation(child.mMeshes, child.mMeshes.length, "a", "b");
            }
        }
    }
```

`pNode.mChildren` is an array of `AiNode`.

This is my `doValidation`

```
private static <T> void doValidation(T[] pArray, int size, String firstName, String secondName) {

        // validate all entries
        if (size > 0) {

            if (pArray == null) {

                throw new Error("aiScene." + firstName + " is NULL (aiScene." + secondName + " is " + size + ")");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                if (pArray[i] != null) {

                    validate(parray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting this error

```
method doValidation in class ValidateDataStructure cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T[],int,String,String
  found: int[],int,String,String
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: int
    upper bound(s): Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>doValidation(T[],int,String,String)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I think it has to do with the fact that arrays of primitive type in java extends Object[], indeed if I switch `T[]` to `T` it works, but then I cannot loop it anymore... I don't know how to solve it or which solutions applies best to my case.

The idea is to have different `validate(T[] array)` based on the array `T` type

Comment: The message says it all. An `int` cannot be a `T`.

Comment: Use Integer[] in place of int[]

Comment: by the way the `T` is unnecessary here; you can just declare it `private static void doValidation(Object[] pArray, int size, String firstName, String secondName)`

Comment: Oh man, you are right..! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is `int[]`, not `Integer[]`. To convert it to `Integer[]` use

```
for (AiNode child : pNode.mChildren) {
    Integer[] meshes = Arrays.stream(child.mMeshes).boxed().toArray(Integer::new);
    doValidation(meshes, child.mMeshes.length, "a", "b");
}
```